# ExtJs 4.1.1 Tree Panel node selection logic

Tags: extjs, tree, treeview, extjs4.1

I am using tree panel is ExtJS.

[image]

Consider the above image as the tree panel. If user selects node 1.1.1.2, I should check if all its sibling are also checked/selected, if yes, system should select 1.1.1 node and deselect 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3 nodes.

Similarly, At this point I should check the siblings of 1.1.1 node (1.1.2 & 1.1.3) & if they previously selected/checked, then I should deselect 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3 and I should select 1.1 node.

This kind of check continues until I reach root node or one the siblings of selected node is not checked/selected.

What is the best way to achieve this. When I say best way, I am looking for some in-build property or method which will help me achieve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the bubble method: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-bubble